# Python error when trying to use multiple functions in a class. Tkinter

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I am having an issue getting this code to parse in tkinter. Two issues happen. I can't get the everb5 variable to pass into the generate function.

```
class App(Tk): 
def __init__(self): 
    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.everb5 = Entry(self).grid(row = 19, column = 2)
    self.btn = Button(self, text = "Generate", command = self.generate).grid(row = 25, column = 3, columnspan = 3)
def generate(self):
    self.everb5.config(text= "Hello")
```

Must I also pass the variable to the generate function like so...

```
def generate(self,everb5)
```

I also have about 23 variables that have to work in the generate function from the init function. Next steps? Variable containing an array of all variables? I am making a mad libs game and need to pass the answers from Tk() Entry() function to generate() and then i planned on using the .format function to replace the "blank spaces" used in mad libs with the answers provided from the user. I have the button working now, I just need to know how to pass the variables between functions.

Comment: Print self everb5.  It is None.  You have to first catch the return from Entry() and then grid() it on a separate line so the None is returned on a separate line.  Next time please include the error message as a None type object, etc. message makes it obvious what is wrong.

Comment: Also you use insert or a textvariable for the Entry widget http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `self.everb5` and `self.btn` are none. The reason is that `grid` returns none. You should execute grid after you make an instance of Entry or Button:

```
class App(Tk): 
    def __init__(self): 
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.everb5 = Entry(self)
        self.everb5.grid(row = 19, column = 2) #<-- here
        self.btn = Button(self, text = "Generate", command = self.generate)
        self.btn.grid(row = 25, column = 3, columnspan = 3) #<-- here

    def generate(self):
        self.everb5.config(text= "Hello")
```

Comment: Apparently it didn't like me trying to use one liners. Thank you, I will make the appropriate changes. Thank you so much